# Cant change python interpreter in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: python, python3, ide

In my console (iterm2)
`which python` gives `/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin/python`

In Visual Studio Code's built in terminal
`which python` gives `/usr/bin/python`

Since I want to use anacondas python installation I use `CMD+SHIFT+P(Python: Select Interpreter)` and there I see `~/anaconda3/bin/python` so I select that one.

However this does not take effect in my terminal. I have tried the following to make it reflect when doing `which python`

- Open a new terminal tab
- Restart program

And if I go back to confirm active interpreter, it does say anaconda. But still it uses the one from `/usr/bin/python`.  Whats going on here?

#### update

`echo $PATH` in visual studio code

```
/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
~/bin:
/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin:
/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:
/Users/anders/.composer/vendor/bin:
/Users/anders/.composer/vendor/bin
```

`echo $PATH` in iterm2

```
/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin:
/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
~/bin:
/Users/anders/.composer/vendor/bin
```

So VS code does something to my PATH but I don't see the pattern.

`echo $SHELL` gives /bin/bash
Putting `export SHELL="/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2"` in my  bash_profile does make VS code to open iterm2 on CMD+ALT+C, but not when switching to the integrated terminal.

I put the following settings in Visual studio code settings (CMD+,)

- `Terminal: Explorer Kind` external
- `Terminal>External: Osx Exec` /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2

Also tried

- `Terminal: Explorer Kind` integrated
- `Terminal>External: Osx Exec` /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2

but *both* of them spawns a new iTerm window that is *not* integrated.

Comment: If downvoting, can you please tell me how to improve the question?

Comment: I couldn't find a tool called visual code. Are you referring to this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: And did the link about the environments shed any light on your problem?

Comment: Thanks, though not really. As the documentation says: "opening a terminal with the Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal command. In the latter case, VS Code automatically activated the selected environment". But im still getting the default interpreter.

Comment: The `$PATH` environment variable is order specific.  In your example where it is working, the `$PATH` has `/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin` before `/usr/bin`.  Try setting the `$PATH` of visual studio code to have your Anaconda directory as the first path and then see if you get the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Correct, do I did not find any way to do that in VS code settings. Do you know how?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Virtual Studio Code does not use the same shell that you're using with iTerm2? According to the [docs on the integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration), the shell that is being used is the one which is set by the `$SHELL` environment variable. Inspect it with:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Furthermore, `which` scans your `$PATH` for an executable and return the first one found. So compare your settings there, too:

```
echo $PATH
```

If that is the issue, you can change `$PATH`, so it will find the `python` in `/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`.

Finally, it might help you to set an alias for `python` in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal. You can set that up with:

```
$ alias python
bash: alias: python: not found
$ alias python=/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin/python
$ alias python
alias python='/Users/anders/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

(`which` might still show the other path, but if you run `python`, you'll get the one from the alias.)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers! Yes, did resort to an alias, but it bugs me and would rather like to configure it to work properly. Please see updated question for some more clues.

Comment: Yes, it is VS code that prepends these paths to PATH when integratd terminal is launched so I dont know how to prevent that. Updating question with what happen when itegrated terminal config is set.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to reset VS Code such that it works again.

Step one: Reset your $PATH variable -> this is temporary because all sorts of funky stuff starts to happen if you reset this:

```
$cd #go to home directory

$nano .bash_profile

# while in nano:

\export PATH="[path to anaconda python3]"

# save and exit

# reset .bash_profile

$. .bash_profile
```

now we need to set PATH to what it was, but `nano`will no longer work, so we put following into the terminal:

```
$usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile

delete the line "\export PATH="[path to anaconda python3]""

# reset .bash_profile again

$. .bash_profile
```

Now if you open up VS Code (or a new terminal in VS Code), it should work!